# Setting default value for CKEditor in Flask App wtforms

Tags: python-3.x, ckeditor, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to set the default value for a CKEditor html text input based on an existing object. The use case is for updating an existing row using flask-sqlalchemy so the user doesn't have to retype all of the existing rich text. As the code is written, the default value for `form.description` is blank even when `object.description` is not.
The relevant part of the form looks something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ ckeditor.load() }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag }}

    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name(class="form-control", value=object.name) }}

    {{ form.description.label }}
    {{ form.description(class="form-control", value=object.description) }}
    
    {{ edit_loc_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
</form>
{{ ckeditor.config(name='description') }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#preset-value-in-ckeditor-textarea):

> If you are using Flask-WTF/WTForms, it’s even more simple, just pass
> the value to the form field’s data attribute:

```
@app.route('/edit')
def edit_post():
    form = EditForm()
    form.body.data = "default value"  # default value entered here.
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use CKEditor Instead of a Form.**

. Passing the Right Variable Object:

While using CKEditor, it's essential to pass the correct variable object to ensure smooth functionality. Double-check that the variable object you are passing contains the necessary data for proper operation.

Setting the Value in CKEditor:
To set the value in CKEditor, follow this syntax:

```
{{ckeditor.create(name=name, value=data_values)}}
```

Handling HTML Tags:
If your data contains HTML tags and you want to render them correctly within CKEditor, use this syntax:

```
{{ckeditor.create(name=name, value=data_values.text)}}
```